Theorem environment using tcolorbox
I am switching from mdframe to tcbcolorbox package in my typed document. To define the theorem environment, I have two options.

To use built in \newtcbtheorem boxes. But this is incorporating labels as a paramenter. It also uses fixed prefix for references. I want my frontend (WinEdt) to gather labels automatically. So, I want to manually provide \label{T:001} et cetera. So, this environment is not suitable for me.

To use tcolorboxenvironment which uses the thm environment provided by amsthm. I want to have the title ''Theorem \thesection.\thethm'' in the title bar. But I do no have any control over removing ''Theorem'' from the content.


How should I overcome this problem?

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}



\theoremstyle{plain}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]

\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\tcbset{colorful/.style={skin=enhanced,fonttitle=\bfseries,
colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black}}


\tcbset{titlecolor/.style={skin=enhanced,fonttitle=\bfseries,
coltitle=black,colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,
segmentation style={black,solid,opacity=0.2,line width=1pt}}}



\newtcbtheorem[use counter=thm,number within = section]{theom}{Theorem}{colback=green!5, colframe=green!35!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,titlecolor,drop large lifted shadow = blue}{}



\tcolorboxenvironment{thm}{
colback=green!5, colframe=green!35!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,titlecolor,drop large lifted shadow = blue,title=Theorem, colupper=black}


\begin{document}

\begin{theom}[label=T:018]{}{}
This is a theorem using newtcbtheorem, as explained in tcolorbox Manual for version 6.4.1 dated 2024/10/22
\end{theom}



\begin{thm}
This is a theorem using tcolorboxenvironment, that reuses already existing amsthm environment defined in the preamble. 
\end{thm}

\end{document}


You can use keytheorems to have tcolorbox theorems with the same input as normal theorems. It uses amsthm under the hood.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{keytheorems}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\tcbset{
  titlecolor/.style={
    skin=enhanced,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    coltitle=black,
    colback=red!5!white,
    colframe=red!75!black,
    segmentation style={black,solid,opacity=0.2,line width=1pt}
    }
  }
\newkeytheoremstyle{tcb-thm}{
  tcolorbox={titlecolor,drop large lifted shadow = blue},
  headpunct={},
  notebraces={}{},
  noteseparator={: },
  notefont=\bfseries,
  bodyfont=\normalfont,
  }
\newkeytheorem{thm}[
  name=Theorem,
  parent=section,
  style=tcb-thm
  ]
 
\begin{document}

\section{Some section}

\ref{foo}

\begin{thm}\label{foo}
This is a theorem using keytheorems. The \verb|\label| command works as expected.
\end{thm}

\end{document}


